# Efficient way to upscale and blur a texture in Metal

Tags: objective-c, macos, metal, metal-performance-shaders

I have some rendering in Metal (macOS) which is fairly expensive, but it's acceptable if the results are slightly blurred. So to optimize things I render to a texture at half the view's resolution, then upscale the result and apply a blur filter (MPS).

To upscale the texture I render it to another texture first and then apply the blur filter which writes the result to the drawable. I'm looking for a technique to avoid this intermediate texture (_texture2), so that the blur filter sources its input from the original texture (_texture1). Perhaps I should write my own blur shader?

```
id <MTLTexture> _texture1; // half the size of the drawable
id <MTLTexture> _texture2; // same size as drawable

id<MTLCommandBuffer> commandBuffer = [_commandQueue commandBuffer];
id<MTLRenderCommandEncoder> renderEncoder =
    [commandBuffer renderCommandEncoderWithDescriptor:...];
            // this encoder renders to _texture1

if (renderEncoder) {

    // do rendering here

    [renderEncoder endEncoding];

    MPSImageBilinearScale* scaleFilter =
        [[MPSImageBilinearScale alloc] initWithDevice:_device];
    scaleFilter.scaleTransform = ...; // enlarge by factor 2
    [_scaleFilter encodeToCommandBuffer:commandBuffer sourceTexture:_texture1
       destinationTexture:_texture2];

    MPSImageGaussianBlur* blurFilter =
        [[MPSImageGaussianBlur alloc] initWithDevice:_device sigma:1.0];
    [_blurFilter encodeToCommandBuffer:commandBuffer sourceTexture:_texture2
        destinationTexture:_view.currentDrawable.texture];

    [commandBuffer presentDrawable:_view.currentDrawable];
}

[commandBuffer commit];
```

Comment: Probably this is a job for Core Image. Use a Metal-based `CIContext`. Create a `CIImage` from your texture. Chain together appropriate `CIFilter`s to scale and blur. Then render to the destination texture.